# ¿Cómo hacer condiciones anidadas en SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de hacer condiciones anidadas para abordar un problema avanzado Select Hackerrank :

Escriba una consulta que identifique el tipo de cada registro en la tabla TRIANGLES utilizando sus tres lados de longitud. Imprima una de las siguientes declaraciones para cada registro en la tabla:

- Equilateral: es un triángulo con lados de igual longitud.
- Isósceles: es un triángulo con lados de igual longitud.
- Scalene: es un triángulo con lados de diferentes longitudes.
- No es un triángulo: los valores dados de A, B y C no forman un triángulo.

Con esto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté el siguiente codigo MySQL :

```
SELECT A,B,C 
    CASE WHEN (A=B AND A=C) THEN 'Equilateral'
    CASE WHEN (A+B>C OR A+C>B OR B+C >A) THEN
        CASE WHEN (A=B OR A=C OR B=C) THEN 'Isoceles'
        ELSE 'Scalene'
    ELSE 'Not A Triangle'
FROM TRIANGLES
```

Pero me devuelve :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN (A=B AND A=C) THEN 'Equilateral' END
    CASE WHEN (A+B>C OR A+C>B OR ' at line 2
```

Intenté envuelvar todos esos casos en uno :

```
SELECT A,B,C 
    CASE WHEN (A=B AND A=C) THEN 'Equilateral' END
    CASE WHEN (A+B>C OR A+C>B OR B+C >A) AND (A=B OR A=C OR B=C) THEN 'Isoceles'END
    CASE WHEN (A+B>C OR A+C>B OR B+C >A) THEN 'Scalene' END
    CASE WHEN (A+B<C OR A+C<B OR B+C <A) THEN 'Not A Triangle' END 
FROM TRIANGLES
```

Comment: no esta mal escrito ese case??? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás usando mal la expresión `CASE`, que tiene la forma:

```
CASE 
    WHEN condición1 THEN valor1
    WHEN condición2 THEN valor2--no debes usar CASE WHEN de nuevo
    ..
    WHEN condiciónN THEN valorN
    ELSE condiciónfinal 
END
```

De esta forma, lo puedes escribir así:

```
SELECT A,B,C,
    CASE WHEN A=B AND A=C THEN 'Equilateral'
         WHEN (A+B>C OR A+C>B OR B+C>A) AND
              (A=B OR A=C OR B=C) THEN Isoceles'
        ELSE 'Scalene'
    END  -- acá falta ver la condición de que no es un triángulo
         -- no puedes tener 2 ELSEs
FROM TRIANGLES
```